# gridster, how to auto fit to browser size change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I'm trying to find a way to auto-resize gridster container.

In a way that when user changes browser size, corresponding gridster widgets resized.
(In which number of columns and rows does not change, but actual size will)

I can calculate the values for "widget_base_dimensions" as browser size changes,

however I couldn't find a way to update/execute to widgets to cope with new size.

I was seeking if there is a function that supports this kind of feature and I noticed that

on line 3529 on jquery.gridster.js,

```
/**
* Recalculates the offsets for the faux grid. You need to use it when
* the browser is resized.
*
* @method recalculate_faux_grid
* @return {Object} Returns the instance of the Gridster class.
*/
fn.recalculate_faux_grid = function() {
    var aw = this.$wrapper.width();
    this.baseX = ($(window).width() - aw) / 2;
    this.baseY = this.$wrapper.offset().top;

    $.each(this.faux_grid, $.proxy(function(i, coords) {
        this.faux_grid[i] = coords.update({
            left: this.baseX + (coords.data.col -1) * this.min_widget_width,
            top: this.baseY + (coords.data.row -1) * this.min_widget_height
        });

    }, this));

    return this;
};
```

I tried to some how utilize them but failed :(

If anyone have been successfully utilized this code or work around, can you please help me?

Comment: have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Should define manuel width over the base dimension `.gridster li{width:34%;}` percentage would make it fit to screen

Comment: better use Packery.js, gridster seems to be unsupported anymore

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I recently came across the container width problem, and spotted that same function in the Gridster source, but having no joy in using it... I raised an issue on GitHub, but got nowhere yet... https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/525

Answer (score 2):

There's long standing [issue #5](https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/5) on project's issue tracket at Github, titled *Auto refresh - Responsive grid* and several others closed as duplicates. There you will find code posted by people trying to add responsiveness to gridster.